# How to use backspace when taking input from user in tcl?

Tags: tcl

Here is part of my code.

```
puts -nonewline "Enter your device name: "
flush stdout
set device [gets stdin]
```

I am taking input from user and if somehow the input is wrong, the user has to kill the code and run it again. Is there any way to use backspace to clear wrong input in tcl.

Comment: Normally the shell handles all the line editing and only passes the complete line to Tcl when the user presses Enter. So, using your code, the backspace key works as expected for me (on linux).

Comment: The code written above is a part of a large script in TCL. In shell the switch -e works fine to remove wrong entry. I wanted to know the same switch which i can integrate in TCL.

Comment: As I indicated, Tcl doesn't get the string until the user presses Enter. The command line editing is handled by the shell from where the Tcl script is executed. So there is nothing that can be done in Tcl for this.

Comment: Some of the `term` packages in tcllib might be helpful for fixing whatever funky state your terminal has been put into.

Comment: Tcl usually expects the terminal to be in cooked+echo mode (or the equivalent on Windows). You can do basic edits to the line such as backspacing to delete characters until you press Return/Enter, which is the first point that Tcl gets to see what is entered at all. In 8.7, you can put the terminal into raw mode, but then you're dealing with _everything_ yourself.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks Donald, Shawn and Schelte.